# Intellij idea preview panel does not reflect changes automatically

Tags: android, xml, intellij-idea, preview

I'm not used to *Intellij Idea* and there is something that feels disconfortable.

Editing my XML file in the editor view does not automatically reflect changes on the *Prewiew panel* which is yet open next to the editor on its right. I also can't move elements around there.

To see changes or drag elements around I must switch to design design tab and get back to the editor.
This is quite annoying, is there a way to fix this through the options/preferences section?

**Intellij Idea screen:**

[image: Screen Intellij Idea]

Comment: Usually the preview is intended to follow modification taken directly into your XML. So you modify your XML and than see your modification in the preview. Is that the you cannot do? Because you also say "I click and hold the button" and I think you did that in the preview area, but that's not good. So if you modify your XML you sound see your changes suddenly in the preview area. Otherwise if you wanna work in a graphical mode you have to choose the design tab.

Comment: Considering also using Android Studio instead of directly go through IntelliJ. Moreover Android Studio is the official IDE for Android based on IntelliJ.